# How to use Flutter OrientationBuilder without GridVeiw

Tags: android, flutter, dart

All `OrientationBuilder` examples I could find use `GridView`.
I wanted to use `Column` and `Row` widgets instead.
This is a code excerpt I used. This works for portrait, but when I turn the phone to landscape, the widgets disappear, I just see background. Turning it back to portrait brings it back to normal.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
   body: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
        if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Widget1(),
              Widget2(),
              Widget3(),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Row(
             children: [
              Widget1(),
              Widget2(),
              Widget3(),
            ],
          );
        }
      }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is nothing wrong with my approach, it's just that my widgets don't fit the screen. Not sure why is nothing displayed, I'd expect something to be visible and yellow/black warning to be displayed.

Anyway, using a table with `FractionColumnWidth` forces the widgets to be rendered on screen even if they don't fit. Building UI with flutter is not going to be easy!

```
 return Table(columnWidths: {
            0: FractionColumnWidth(.25),
            1: FractionColumnWidth(.5),
            2: FractionColumnWidth(.25)
          }, children: <TableRow>[
            TableRow(children: [
              Widget1(),
              Widget2(),
              Widget3(),
            ]),
          ]);
```